# Many to many relation " Column doesn't exist" Hibernate & Springboot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm writting first app using spring and hibernate I have problem with Many to Many relation. When I'm executing code it gives me error : column subject0_.subject_name doesn't exist. It is very strange to me because my table is called subject not subject0.
Below code of my "class"  class

```
@Entity
public class Class {
@NotNull
@Id
@Column(name = "class_name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "start_year")
private int startYear;


@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "Class_has_Subject", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "class_name")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "subject_name")})
private Set<Subject> subject = new HashSet<Subject>(0);

public Set<Subject> getSubject() {
    return this.subject;
}


public void setSubject(Set<Subject> subject) {
    this.subject = subject;
}

public int getStartYear() {
    return startYear;
}

public void setStartYear(int startYear) {
    this.startYear = startYear;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Class() {
}


}
```

Subject Class :

```
@Entity(name = "subject")

public class Subject {

 @NotNull
@Id
@Column(name = "subject_name")
private String name;
@Column(name = "teacher")
private String teacher;
public Subject(String name, String teacher) {
    this.name = name;
    this.teacher = teacher;
}

public Subject() {
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getTeacher() {
    return teacher;
}
public void setTeacher(String teacher) {
    this.teacher = teacher;
}
}
```

ClassRepository interface :

```
public interface ClassRepository extends CrudRepository<Class,String> {
List<Class> findByName(String name);
}
```

Classcontroller class :

```
@Controller

@EnableAutoConfiguration

public class ClassController {

@Autowired
ClassRepository repo;

@RequestMapping(value = "/class/get/{name}/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Set<Subject> getClass(@PathVariable String name) {

    Class a= repo.findByName(name).get(0);
    System.out.println(a.getStartYear());
    Set<Subject> s=a.getSubject();
    return s;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

subject0_ is the name that hibernate gives to your table. It is not the actual name of the table. So when hibernate tries to query your class table it will construct a sql command like the following

```
select
        class0_.class_name as class_na1_2_,
        class0_.start_year as start_ye2_2_ 
    from
        public.class class0_ 
    where
        class0_.class_name=?
```

Note "class0_" is the reference to the "class" table.

If you are using spring boot, you can configure hibernate to log these sql commands for debugging, by putting the following two lines in your application.properties.

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true
```

Other environments will their ways to configure hibernate.

That said, there doesn't seem to be any problem with your mapping. My hunch is that your subject table does not have the "subject_name" column, because you missed to manually add it or hibernate is unable to add it when you are starting your application.

If you like hibernate to update your tables based on your entity definitions you can use its hbm2ddl functionality. To do that in a Spring Boot application you should have the following line in your application.properties:

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = update

Answer (score -1):

check your ManyToMany mapping for  Subject

Comment: Needs more explanation.

Comment: give us sql generated by hibernate

Comment: Can you tell me how to do this?